# Triggering hover on map tiles in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I want to trigger a jquery event on mouseover of tiles in Google Maps. The best I could come up with was.

```
$('div.tileclass').live('hover', function(){
   $("#debugger").prepend("test");  //Dummy just to test if this works
});
```

This triggers the hover action only while the map is loading but not once the page is loaded

Can be seen here: http://rider.cyclistsroadmap.com  (though the debugger div won't be displayed and alerts tend to be annoying for testing and hope up the map loading)

Any way to be able to trigger actions after the page is loaded

Comment: I added the css " pointer-events: none" to one of the other layers using Firebug and teh even worked perfectly!  Any idea of how i can add this the css of the other layer from javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event listener to the map's mousemove event, such as:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'mousemove', function(mev){
    var TILE_SIZE = 256;
    var proj = map.getProjection();
    var numTiles = 1 << map.getZoom();
    var worldCoordinate = proj.fromLatLngToPoint(mev.latLng);

    var pixelCoordinate = new google.maps.Point(
            worldCoordinate.x * numTiles,
            worldCoordinate.y * numTiles);
        var tileCoordinate = new google.maps.Point(
            Math.floor(pixelCoordinate.x / TILE_SIZE),
            Math.floor(pixelCoordinate.y / TILE_SIZE));

    debug('TileX:' +tileCoordinate.x+' - TileY:'+tileCoordinate.y);

});
```

Note that the debug() function is contained in this [separate file](http://maps.forum.nu/v3/debug.js)

The code posted here is largely based on [**this example**](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates) from the documentation.